# How would this lambda function reduce?

Tags: logic, notation, lambda-calculus

Let's say I have `TRUE` and `FALSE` defined as follows:

$$\pmb{T} = \lambda ab.a$$
$$\pmb{F} = \lambda ab.b$$

Now I can define a `NOT` as something like the following:

$$\pmb{N} = \lambda p.p F T$$

My question is if I were to substitute in the `T` and `F`, how would I properly reduce that function? For example:

\begin{align}
\pmb{N} & = \lambda p.p F T \\
        & = \lambda p.p (\lambda ab.a) (\lambda ab.b)
\end{align}

How does it get reduced from there?

(And on another note, is there a way to (1) align the equations in TeX so the `N` will be left-aligned? and (2) is there a way to put italic comments to the right of the equation to show what I'm doing in that step?)

Comment: For your (1) and (2), search "\begin{align}" and "\tag" respectively.

Comment: I think: $$\lambda p.p (\lambda ab.a) (\lambda ab.b)$$ is ambiguous. It could mean $$(\lambda p.p) (\lambda ab.a) (\lambda ab.b)$$ or $$\lambda p.(p (\lambda ab.a) (\lambda ab.b))$$ Here, you want the latter.

Comment: I guess even $\lambda p.pFT$ is ambiguous...

Comment: There is no further reduction for $N.$ 
What you then want to reduce is $NT$ and $NF.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews hm...could you explain that a bit. Perhaps just showing how something like $NT$ or $NF$ reduces would explain it all.